# (Baby maths) Sum of three positive integers = odd or even? + more info

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm struggling to understand this basic question:

$x$, $y$, and $z$ are positive integers. Is $x+y+z$ even?

Supposedly you can derive the answer, from these two pieces of information separately:

$x-y-z$ is odd,

and;

$xyz$ is odd.

How do you approach this problem? / What do I need to learn?

Comment: Just think for a while.  If $xyz$ is odd can any of the parts be even?

Comment: Suppose $x+y+z$ is even. Given that $x-y-z$ is odd, their sum must be odd but $(x+y+z)+(x-y-z)=2x$ is a multiple of $2$, hence even, a contradiction. You don't need the additional info that $xyz$ is odd.

Comment: You can also do this using only the second info: a product $\prod_i a_i$ of integers is odd iff all the $a_i$ are odd (prove this!), so $x+y+z$ is the sum of 3 odd numbers, hence odd.

Comment: @learner  OP said those assumptions are to be used separately.

Comment: @Randall: hmm, you're right. I initially thought both of them were to be used together but did notice that any one of them is sufficient to conclude. My comments still apply.

Answer (score 4):

in general $x+y+z$ is odd, if and only if $x,y$ and $z$ are all odd, or only one of $x,y$ and $z$ is odd. This is consequence of the fact that odd+odd=even, even+even=even and odd+even=odd.

See if you can come up with similar rules, but then for multiplication and subtraction.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the answers!

I learnt that I should have tried representing the variables differently, as in $2a + 1$ for odd numbers and $2a$ for even numbers.
I guess I have to become more familiar with all those "even + odd = odd" etc.

Also, I think *learner*'s idea was quite clever because of how quick it was.

*Some context if you're interested*: This question is from an old test and you have roughly two minutes per question, but you don't have to give an exact answer, you just have to deduce whether the information given is insufficient or the least information you can solve it with.